# Запись в массив по индексу Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, frontend, knockoutjs

Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке записи в observableArray по определённому индексу.

```
function AppViewModel(){
this.curNumber = ko.observable("");
this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
this.addNumber = function() { this.numbers[curNumber]++;}
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Код страницы

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: curNumber">
<button data-bind="click: addNumber">Добавить</button>
```

Я ожидаю, что при вводе, например, цифры "1" и нажатии кнопки "Добавить", первое значение в массиве numbers увеличиться на единицу, однако этого не происходит.
Вероятнее всего решение лежит на поверхности, однако я его не нашёл

Answer (score 1):

[документация](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

> Not all browsers support JavaScript getters and setters (* cough * IE
>    * cough *), so for compatibility, ko.observable objects are actually **functions**.
>
> - To read the observable’s current value, just call the observable with
>     no parameters. In this example, myViewModel.personName() will return 'Bob', and myViewModel.personAge() will return 123.
> - To write a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass the new value as a parameter. For example, calling
>     myViewModel.personName('Mary') will change the name value to 'Mary'.

То есть `curNumber` и `numbers` - это функции. Используются так:

```
this.curNumber();  //возвращает curNumber
this.curNumber(5); //устанавливает curNumber=5
```

`observableArray` позволяет knockout следить за изменениями массива (добавление, удаление элементов), но при этом изменения значений останутся незамеченными. Поэтому следует самому сделать каждый элемент `observable`:

```
this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].map(function(value){
  return ko.observable(value);
}));
```

Тогда массив можно использовать как в предыдущем примере:

```
this.numbers()[i]()  //возвращает i-тый элемент 
this.numbers()[i](5) //устанавливает numbers[i]=5
```

Таким образом функция `addNumber` может быть такой:

```
var index=this.curNumber();
var value=this.numbers()[index]();
this.numbers()[index](value+1);
```